# react-bootstrap not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use react-bootstrap to style a web page.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "chrome-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.16"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

function CheckState(props){
    function handleClick(e){
        console.log(props.state)
    }
    return(
        <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={handleClick}>Click for state</Button>
    )
}
```

However this is what I'm seeing on the web page when I refresh:

[image]

It doesn't look like the styling is being added. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the stylesheets to your html? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html

Comment: In addition to the `react-bootstrap` - `npm i bootstrap --save-dev` and add `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` in your App.js

Comment: that was it, thank you. @elmeister if you put as an answer i'll mark as correct

Answer (score 18):

Add import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"; in your index.js

Comment: That solved. But why? They didn't mentioned about this is Docs.

Comment: But bootstrap mention about it. ***Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components.*** https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets

Comment: now it is import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' 
always refer to the docs as @Piotr mentioned

Answer (score 3):

In your react application, open index.js file and add `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`